# How to except the " ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(992)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107 " or hide this?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Ive created an script to automate it does the job correctly but this
`ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(992)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107` come along with it

```
C:\Users\Eren Jaeger\Desktop\auto\mg.py:19: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\Eren Jaeger\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
C:\Users\Eren Jaeger\Desktop\auto\mg.py:19: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
  driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\Eren Jaeger\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:65169/devtools/browser/d859babc-9a80-4c70-8d3a-c2ec43548ef5
[0430/161945.571:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(992)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
[0430/161945.763:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(992)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
[0430/161946.122:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(992)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
[0430/161946.136:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(992)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
[0430/161946.139:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(992)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
[0430/161949.106:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(992)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
[0430/161949.977:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(992)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
[0430/161950.015:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(992)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
[0430/161950.018:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(992)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
[0430/161950.022:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(992)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
[0430/161950.025:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(992)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
[0430/161950.027:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(992)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
[0430/161952.741:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(992)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
Your attendance percentage is:73.83
```